# Does zinc react with nitrogen?

Tags: metal

Does zinc react with nitrogen ?
Is this reaction possible:

3Zn + N<sub>2</sub> → Zn<sub>3</sub>N<sub>2</sub>

Or maybe there are another reaction?

Comment: Yes, it does. $\ce{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_nitride) gives several synthetic routes to zinc nitride.  One of these routes is electrical discharge between zinc electrodes in a nitrogen atmosphere.  Synthesis without electrical discharge generally uses ammonia as the ultimate nitrogen source.